# passing items from list to an empty object in another list

Tags: python, list, nested-loops

I want to pass items from lists to the empty object in store i.e. I want:

```
store = [ [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']], [] ]
```

I am getting an unintended result:

```
lists = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]

store = [[], []]


counter = 0
for l in lists:
    for s in store:
        s.append(l)
```

which gives me:

```
store = [[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']], [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]]
```

Comment: I dont understand what you intend to do

Comment: @abc: Can you please be more specific to your question. I am not able to get what is the desired behaviour. Providing sample input and desired output will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If

```
store = [ [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']], [] ]
```

is indeed what you want, then you've overshot the mark. The inner loop is unnecessary and will execute your code for *each* item in `store`. You have two empty lists in `store`, thus creating two populated lists in `store` after the code has run. To just do the first one, you want

```
for l in lists:
    store[0].append(l)
```

Reading your question though I'm not 100% positive that's what you're actually after, esp. given your otherwise mysterious inner loop.

I read "I want to pass items from lists to the empty object in store" as possibly meaning you're trying to take items from two lists in `lists` and make them one list in `store`. If that's what you want, something like this would do the trick:

```
for l in lists:
    for i in l:
        store[0].append(i)
```

which gives you:

```
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], []]
```

Answer (score 1):

The nested for loop is an overkill. You should instead `extend` the first sublist in `store` with `lists`:

```
lists = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]
store = [[], []]

store[0].extend(lists)
#     ^ indexing starts from 0
print(store)
# [[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']], []]
```

Have a look at more on [`lists`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)

Answer (score 0):

Store has two empty lists, and you're adding on to both of them.  If you only want to add onto the first then

```
for l in lists:
    store[0].append(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple man. 
The best way to do this would be to simply assign the lists to stores[0].

```
stores[0]= lists
```

is all you need to do.

Comment: See what happens to `store` with `lists.append(0)` after the assignment. Not sure if OP wants that behaviour

Answer (score 0):

How about simply doing this:

```
store = [lists, []]
# value of 'store' = [[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']], []]
```

As I believe based on your question, that the desired O/P is:

```
store = [ [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']], [] ]
```

from the input list:

```
lists = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]
```

Comment: This has the effect of modifying `store`, when `lists` is modified. Not sure OP wants that behaviour

Comment: @MosesKoledoye : Question from OP is not clear. Even I do not believe he would be asking for the solution what I mentioned. But on going through the question, this is what I felt. I already left a comment for him a long back regarding the clarity of his requirement, but no response yet